# Removing sidebar in Wordpress when using Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, wordpress

I am using fancybox for Wordpress here: http://www.nawair.dk/?gallery=299-2
I would really like to remove the sidebar, and have tried to remove this php-line:  in this file: nawair.dk/wp-content/themes/portfolio-press/gallery-template.php, but that does not help.
Does anyone have a suggestion, please?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Best, Jens

Comment: what is the idea of removing the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

A 'sidebar' or 'widgetized area' in WordPress consists of two portions. The sidebar definition and its implementation.

The definition of the sidebar creates the name and description you see from the Widgets admin panel, as well as allows the theme to define wrapping markup for the sidebar. This is done with the `register_sidebar()` [`register_sidebars()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars) functions. The second obviously being used for registering multiple sidebars at once. This is typically done in functions.php - however in reality this can be done on any template in the theme, or even from a plugin.

The implementation of a sidebar is done on the template you want it to show up on and inline. The function used for this is [`dynamic_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar), and the only argument that needs to be passed is the `'name'` which the sidebar was given when it was defined.

To remove your mystery sidebar, look in your Widget admin panel and find out its name, look in functions.php to remove its definition, and then look for its implementation to remove it as well. If either or neither is found in an obvious location, just run a search across your whole theme for `'dynamic_sidebar'` and/or `'register_sidebar` - or even simpler, just search for the name of the sidebar itself, that should bring return both the definition and implementation.

Note:
I realized you may only want to remove it from the specific page on which your using the fancybox gallery, from what I can tell (from inspecting the page's source), is a single post of post_type 'gallery'. If this is the only type of place you want it removed, and your sidebar is on some generic template like 'index.php', then you might just want to wrap it with a conditional tag as such:

```
if(is_single() && 'gallery' == get_post_type()){
   dynamic_sidebar('Your Sidebar');
}
```

Of course I am guessing as to the conditions you want, so please look over the [Conditional Tags page in the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)